# cannot figure out why the file will not copy

Tags: bash, for

I am trying to write a program which i can reuse for copying content into multiple directories. But for the life of it i cannot figure out why the program does not work and is throwing this error.

I have a file with the names of the folders to which i need to copy.

```
test1
test2
test3
```

i am trying to copy a file called default.meta to each of the above mentioned folders using the following command.

```
while read $line;
do 
cp -r default.meta $line;
done < test
```

and when i run the command i get the following error and for the life of it i cannot figure out why this dont work.

```
cp: missing destination file operand after ‘default.meta’
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
cp: missing destination file operand after ‘default.meta’
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
cp: missing destination file operand after ‘default.meta’
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
cp: missing destination file operand after ‘default.meta’
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: what's the value of $line?

Comment: Read takes the name of the variable. `read -r line`. As your `read $line` is not quoted and `line` is initially undefined, `read` gets no variable name after expansion, and is reading the names into `REPLY` by default. Also, if the target name contains whitespace, cp will get too many words. Quote all expansions !

Comment: @Paul_Pedant that's actually an answer, not just a comment.  and not just a minimal answer, it's one with a good, concise explanation.

Comment: i am just so stupid. i was staring at the screen for so long i couldnt figure out what was there all along. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on the previous comments i was giving blank values to the 'line' variable. it should have read

```
while read line; do  cp -r ./default.meta "$line"; done < test
```

Comment: You'd want to read [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)

Comment: Also note that with the GNU implementation of `cp`, you need `--` after `-r` even though `./default.meta` is a non-option argument.

Comment: With GNU `xargs`, see also: `xargs -rd '\n' -n1 -a test cp -r -- ./default.meta`